# Uploading data on SQL Server using Bulk Insert and defining Field Quote

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to upload dummy data which would help in uploading bigger files.
The dummy data is as follows:

```
+---------+-------+----------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Name   | Class | Subject  |  ExamDate  | Mark |                           Description                         |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Prabhat |     4 | "Math"   | 02/10/2013 |   25 |    "Test data for prabhat.'                                     |
| Murari  |     5 |"Science" | 02/11/2013 |   24 |    "Test data for his's test, where we can test 2nd ROW, Test." |
| sanjay  |     4 | "Science"|            |   25 | "Test Only."                                                    |
| xyz     |     5 |"Science,"|            |      |       ""                                                        |
+---------+-------+----------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The problem that forces me to upload data through `BULK INSERT` is that I do not want to change the data type of `ExamDate` column to `date` after uploading it.

Therefore, I created a table and uploaded data through bulk insert using following piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[Class] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[Subject] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
[ExamDate] date NULL,
[Mark] INT NULL,
[Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL 
)


BULK INSERT test_data
FROM 'D:\TP - Churn\text.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '"\"',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK

)
```

The above query gives the an error as follows `Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'`.
Removing `FORMAT = 'CSV'` line and executing would give the same error but this time with `FIELDQUOTE`.

The point of introducing `FIELDQUOTE = '"'` is to deal with the last row, where in `subject` column there is a `,` after science. This entry in csv looks like `"Science,"` .

As per [Incorrect syntax near format in BULK INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42207056/incorrect-syntax-near-format-in-bulk-insert) I think we can not use `FIELDQUOTE` while using SQL Server 2016.

Edit:
So far I've managed to this with a format file as follows:

If that is true than how do we deal with the issue stated above?

```
11.0
6
1   SQLCHAR   0  8000  ","      1     Name          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2   SQLCHAR   0  40    ","      2     Class         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3   SQLCHAR   0  40    "\","    3     Subject       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4   SQLCHAR   0  40    ","      4     ExamDate      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5   SQLCHAR   0  40    ","      5     Mark          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6   SQLCHAR   0  1000  "\"\r\n" 6     Description   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The results are as follow:

```
+---------+-------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  Name   | Class |  Subject  |  ExamDate  | Mark |                         Description                         |
+---------+-------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Prabhat |     4 | "Math     | 10/02/2013 | 25   | "Test data for prabhat.                                     |
| Murari  |     5 | "Science  | 11/02/2013 | 24   | "Test data for his's test, where we can test 2nd ROW, Test. |
| sanjay  |     4 | "Science  | NULL       | 25   | "Test Only.                                                 |
| xyz     |     5 | "Science, | NULL       | NULL | "                                                           |
+---------+-------+-----------+------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The quotes at the beginning are not being removed in both `Subject` & `Description` column. Furthermore, last row and last column was empty but in the results its not NULL.

Result of file opened in notepad:

```
Prabhat,4,"Math",02/10/2013,25,"Test data for prabhat."
Murari,5,"Science",02/11/2013,24,"Test data for his's test, where we can test 2nd ROW, Test."
sanjay,4,"Science",,25,"Test Only."
xyz,5,"Science,",,,""
```

Comment: `FIELDQUOTE` was added in SQL Server 2017, so no, it's not available in SQL Server 2016. Have you considered changing your file to something else (such as Pipe Delimited), or using an ETL tool (like SSIS)?

Comment: This is an example file which can easily be converted to Pipe Delimited but I want to do this task on 3-4 bigger files which would be costly. Haven't used an ETL tool.

Comment: Does your file really look exactly like that? Does it really have all those `+`, `-`, `|` in it? If your file really looks like that you can treat it as pipe delimited or fixed width. If your file doesn't really look like that, you need to post what we are actually working with. Can you clarify: `ExamDate` will eventually reside in a field of type `date` right? Never store dates as strings

Comment: ExamDate will reside in a field of type date. There might be NULLS in ExamDate. Moreover, there won't be any +, -, or | but you can expect , as demonstrated in last row 3rd column.

Comment: There is no point pursuing this question unless you can describe the file format. Is it delimited? Is it fixed width? Is it a text file? Excel? Please edit your question and describe the actual format, for example is it CSV? CSV (comma seperated) is both the most widely used and yet the most error prone. Tab or pipe delimited is far more reliable due to the comma issue you describe

Comment: In a nutshell the problem is to define text qualifier as " while using using bulk insert query.

Comment: But your posted sample data has no `"` in it anywhere.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've made some edits.

Comment: Your posted sample is still pipe delimited - is that what you're loading? Open your source file in notepad and paste whats in there. Don't try formatting it.